# How to use function pointers properly in c

Tags: c, function-pointers

I have this problem:

I have a program that calculates the execute time of two algorithms (shellsort and insertion sort) each in three different arrays(most favorable case, most unfavorable case and random case) so basically I need to do a function that does the same thing six times (shell sort most favorable case, shell sort most unfavorable case and shell sort random case, and the same thing to insertion sort) but I don't want to copy&paste the code six times, and a function with six cases isn't very efficient. So I was trying to understand pointers to function but I don't know how I can use it there. This is my code:

```
void testInsMostUnfavorableCase()
{
    int i,j,n=500,K=1000,p=0;
    double c,d,t1,t2,t;
    printf("Insertion sort on most unfavorable case\n");
    printf("%9s%20s%12s%12s%12s\n", "n","t(n)","t(n)/n^0.8","t(n)/n","t(n)/nlogn");
    for(i=1;i<8;i++)
    {       
        int v[n];
        descending(v,n); //THERE
        c=microseconds();
        ins_sort(v,n); //THERE
        d=microseconds();
        t=d-c;
        if(t<500) /*times <500ms */
        {
            p=1;
            c=microseconds();
            for(j=0;j<K;j++)
            {
                descending(v,n); //THERE
                ins_sort(v,n); //THERE
            }
            d=microseconds();
            t1=d-c;
            c=microseconds();
            for(j=0;j<K;j++)
                descending(v,n); //THERE
            d=microseconds();
            t2=d-c;
            t=(t1-t2)/K;
            printf("%3s%6d%20.3f%12f%12f%12f\n","(*)",n,t,t/pow(n,0.8),t/n,t/(n*log(n)));
        }
        else
            printf("%9d%20.3f%12f%12f%12f\n",n,t,t/pow(n,0.8),t/n,t/(n*log(n)));
        n=n*2;
    }
    if(p==1)
            printf("%s%d%s\n","*: Average time (in microseconds) of ",K," algorithm executions." );
}

void testInsMostFavorableCase() {...}
void testInsRandomCase() {...}
void testShellMostUnfavorableCase() {...}
void testShellMostFavorableCase() {...}
void testShellRandomCase() {...}
```

The problem is that I have to repeat it six times to change the commented lines with THERE. Do you have any other solutions using pointers to functions or something?

Comment: What's "descending" for? I assume it moves around the data in some way that's unfavourable for the sort algorithm?

Comment: Sorry, I forget that. Descending initialices a descending array to sort the most unfavorable array. Example: {5,4,3,2,1,0}. Ascending does {0,1,2,3,4,5} and random does {0,4,2,5,3,1}

Answer (score 1):

> I don't want to copy&paste the code six times

Then don't. The three test cases differ only by the input data ->

`benchmarkInsertionSort( int[] data, int dataSize)`

You'll *write* this function *once* per algorithm and call it once for each test data set, like

```
benchmarkInsertionSort(dataset1, 500);
benchmarkInsertionSort(dataset2, 500);
benchmarkInsertionSort(dataset3, 500);
```

In your code, separate the setup of each test run (e.g. `int v[n]; descending(v,n);`) from the actual operations to test.

If you really wanted to, you could use function pointers to make the benchmark code a little more generic:

```
// Define a type for a pointer to a void function with two arguments (int[],int):
typedef void (*sort_function_t)(int[] data, int size);

// A function compatible with the pointer type above:
void ins_sort( int[] data, int size ) {
    ...
}

// Another function compatible with the pointer type above:
void shell_sort( int[] data, int size ) {
    ...
}

void benchmarkSortAlgo( sort_function_t sortFunction, int[] data, int dataSize ) {
  ...
  // Call the function pointed to by the sortFuntion parameter:
  sortFunction(data,dataSize);
  ...
}

...
// Pass pointers to the sort function to the benchmark.
// Note that we get the pointer to a function by just using 'functionname' without any parenthesis! 
benchmarkSortAlgo( ins_sort, testData1, 500 );
benchmarkSortAlgo( shell_sort, testData2, 500 );
...
```

Answer (score 0):

It follows an example that compiles from which to  get inspiration.
It is fully based on your code, so it still requires changes, for I've added only the pointers to the functions marked with *THERE*.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

typedef void(*fnptr)(int*, int);

void test(
    fnptr descending_ptr,
    fnptr ins_sort_ptr
    )
{
    int i,j,n=500,K=1000,p=0;
    double c,d,t1,t2,t;
    printf("%9s%20s%12s%12s%12s\n", "n","t(n)","t(n)/n^0.8","t(n)/n","t(n)/nlogn");
    for(i=1;i<8;i++)
    {
        int v[n];
        descending_ptr(v,n); //THERE
        c=microseconds();
        ins_sort_ptr(v,n); //THERE
        d=microseconds();
        t=d-c;
        if(t<500) /*times <500ms */
        {
            p=1;
            c=microseconds();
            for(j=0;j<K;j++)
            {
                descending_ptr(v,n); //THERE
                ins_sort_ptr(v,n); //THERE
            }
            d=microseconds();
            t1=d-c;
            c=microseconds();
            for(j=0;j<K;j++)
                descending_ptr(v,n); //THERE
            d=microseconds();
            t2=d-c;
            t=(t1-t2)/K;
            printf("%3s%6d%20.3f%12f%12f%12f\n","(*)",n,t,t/pow(n,0.8),t/n,t/(n*log(n)));
        }
        else
            printf("%9d%20.3f%12f%12f%12f\n",n,t,t/pow(n,0.8),t/n,t/(n*log(n)));
        n=n*2;
    }
    if(p==1)
            printf("%s%d%s\n","*: Average time (in microseconds) of ",K," algorithm executions." );
}

void test() { /* ... */ }

double microseconds() { return 0; }
void descendingInsMostFavorableCase(int*, int) { /* ... */ }
void insSortInsMostFavorableCase(int*, int) { /* ... */ }

int main() {
    printf("Insertion sort on most favorable case\n");
    test(&descendingInsMostFavorableCase, &insSortInsMostFavorableCase);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the title of the question, here are some hints of how to do this with generic programming. That is: how you would implement these sorting algorithms for real-world use, outside academic-only purposes.

To break up those different functions you have into parameters, it would seem that you need the following things:

- The sort algorithm.
- The data to test it with
- The size of the data
- In a generic algorithm, the size of one data item
- In a generic algorithm, a comparison function ("functor")

If you are to have the sort algorithm as a parameter to a function, you would first need to standardize its format. It might at the same time be a good idea to implement it as a generic sort function which can accept any type.

To achieve this, you can look at how standard C library `qsort` is implemented, for an idea how to write a generic sort algorithm:

```
void qsort(void *base, size_t nmemb, size_t size,
     int (*compar)(const void *, const void *));
```

`base` is the array of data, `nmemb` is the number of objects, `size` is the size of each object and `compar` is a function pointer to a comparison function.

The comparison function should be implemented so that given two parameters `a` and `b`, it will return a positive value if `a > b`, a negative value if `a < b` and 0 if `a == b`. So for signed integer data the function would simply consist of one line `return a - b;`. (It works exactly like strcmp, memcmp etc.)

If you use this concept of writing a sort function, you can then typedef the  comparison function as:

```
typedef int compare_t (const void*, const void*);
```

All your sort functions would then have a standard signature like for example:

```
void insertion_sort (void*      base,
                     size_t     n,
                     size_t     obj_size,
                     compare_t* comp);
```

Meaning you can typedef that function signature too:

```
typedef void sort_t (void*      base,
                     size_t     n,
                     size_t     obj_size,
                     compare_t* comp);
```

And then you would end up with a benchmark function looking like:

```
void benchmark (sort_t*    sort, 
                void*      base,
                size_t     n,
                size_t     obj_size,
                compare_t* comp)
{
   // set up & start timer etc

   sort(base, n, obj_size, comp);

   // stop timer
   // print results
}
```

And finally, your main would look like this, example with integer:

```
benchmark(insertion_sort,
          most_favourable, // this is an int array
          sizeof(most_favourable) / sizeof(*most_favourable),
          sizeof(int),
          compare_int);

benchmark(insertion_sort,
          random_case, // this is an int array
          sizeof(random_case) / sizeof(*random_case),
          sizeof(int),
          compare_int);
```

And so on. In the caller, you can create numerous test cases, with different data, different data types etc.